# extra "file://" prefix generated by pdflatex using hyperref package in macro

Tags: latex, hyperref

The LaTeX hyperref package confuses me in several ways. Here's my particular problem.

In my document, the command

```
\footnote{
\url{http://www.boston.com/news/science/articles/2010/04/25/new_atlas_shows_the_state_of_nature_as_well_as_the_nature_of_states/}
}
```

works just fine - pdflatex generates just the valid link.

But the commands

```
\newcommand{\webref}[1]{\footnote{\url{#1}}}

\webref{http://www.boston.com/news/science/articles/2010/04/25/new_atlas_shows_the_state_of_nature_as_well_as_the_nature_of_states/
}
```

generates the link

```
file:///C|/eb/qrbook/%20http://www.boston.com/news/science/articles/2010/04/25/new_atlas_shows_the_state_of_nature_as_well_as_the_nature_of_states/
```

Can someone tell me where the extra "file://..." comes from, and how to get rid of it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wild guess: Are you sure you're not introducing any extraneous spaces anywhere? I can reproduce the behaviour if I introduce a linebreak just before `#1`. (Pro tip: Put a `%` just after the last character in multi-line commands, so LaTeX doesn't process the newline.)

Comment: Maybe a wild guess, but a correct one. I discovered it for myself, but neglected to check back here to answer my own question - and to discover your answer. Thanks.